# Fill under a normal distribution

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing

I have a normal distribution function using tikz that I cannot fill the area under the curve.

Here is my minimal code:

```
    \documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}
      \tikzset{declare function={myGauss(\x,\y,\z)=exp(-(\x-\y)*(\x-\y)/(\z*\z));}}
      % this is a Gaussian centered at \y with a width controlled by \z
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [thick] (0,0)--(5,0);
        \foreach \x in {0,...,5}
          \draw[xshift=\x cm, thick] (0pt,-1pt)--(0pt,1pt) node[below] {$\x$};
          \draw plot[fill=red,domain=0:5,variable=\x,samples=100] ({\x},{myGauss(\x,4.24,0.43)});
      \end{tikzpicture}\par
    \end{document}
```

I would like to create a solid fill under the normal distribution curve and have not had any luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: fill under a gaussian]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{declare function={myGauss(\x,\y,\z)=exp(-(\x-\y)*(\x-\y)/(\z*\z));}}
% this is a Gaussian centered at \y with a width controlled by \z
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\mygaussian{plot[domain=0:5,variable=\x,samples=100] ({\x},{myGauss(\x,4.24,0.43)})}
        \fill[cyan] (0,0)  \mygaussian -- (5,0) -- cycle ;
        \draw \mygaussian;
        
        \draw [thick] (0,0)--(5,0);
        \foreach \x in {0,...,5}
        \draw[xshift=\x cm, thick] (0pt,-1pt)--(0pt,1pt) node[below] {$\x$};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick beautifully. :)

Comment: You may raise your number of samples (say to 200) to produce a smoother curve, also.